# Print reports using a PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, report, dompdf

How can I print reports using a PDF? Now, I use a dompdf for printing reports but our panel said that when a report has been viewed there should be a button for cancel.

But the pdf form that should appear has a print and cancel button when the button for generating report has been clicked. Are there any methods of generating report with a PDF except dompdf?

*dompdf-master* was the name of the folder in my local system and here's the sample code to generate a report:

```php
<?php
include('../connect-db-i.php');
require_once("../dompdf-master/dompdf_config.inc.php");

session_start();

ob_start();
?>
```

Here's the style for the report

```css
<style>
<!-- CSS RESET -->
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

<!-- CSS RESET -->

html {
    margin: auto;
}

table {
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

th {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

th {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 5px 24px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: auto;
}

#mainCont {
    margin: auto 18px 5px 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

#img_main_logo {
    width: 200px;
    padding: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

#imgCont {
    margin: 6px;
    float: left;
}

#textCont {
    margin: 6px;
    float: right;
    width: 880px;
    height: 40px;
}

.title {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#center {
    text-align: center;
}

#title {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#main_title {
    font-size: 22px;
}
</style>
```

Here's the start of the report

```php
<?php
$month = date('F');

if($month == 'June' || $month == 'July' || $month == 'August' || $month == 'September' || $month == 'October' || $month == 'November' || $month == 'December')
{
    $year1 = date('Y');
    $year2 = date('Y') + 1;
    $preyear1 = date('Y') - 1;
    $preyear2 = date('Y');

    $schoolyear = $year1 . " - " . $year2;
    $preschoolyear = $preyear1 . " - " . $preyear2;
}

if($month == 'January' || $month == 'February' || $month == 'March' || $month == 'April' || $month == 'May')
{
    $year1 = date('Y') - 1;
    $year2 = date('Y');
    $preyear1 = date('Y');
    $preyear2 = date('Y') + 1;

    $schoolyear = $year1 . " - " . $year2;
    $preschoolyear = $preyear1 . " - " . $preyear2;
}
?>
```

Here's the html for the report

```html
<html>
<body style="font-family: Helvetica;">
    <div id="mainCont">
        <div id="imgCont">
            <img id="img_main_logo" src="../image/logo/bnhslogo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainCont">
    <table border="0px">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div id="textCont">
                    <p class="info" style="text-align: center;">
                    PTA ORGANIZATION
                    <br>BACNOTAN NATIONAL HIGH SCHOOL
                    <br>BACNOTAN, LA UNION
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0px" style="margin-top: 60px;">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th style='text-align: center;'>
                <b>DAILY REPORT OF GENERAL PTA</b>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th style='text-align: center;'>
                <b>FOR SCHOOL YEAR <?php echo $schoolyear; ?> </b>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th id = 'main_title'>PTA Fees and Authorized Fees<br></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <table border="0px;" style="text-align: left;">
        <?php
            $user = $_SESSION['userlogin'];

            $student = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE schoolyear = '$schoolyear' AND status = 'Enrolled' OR status = 'Dropped'");
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($student);

            $result_collection = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM collection WHERE schoolyear = '$schoolyear' AND type_trans = 'Daily'");
            $count_coll = mysqli_num_rows($result_collection);

            if($count_coll == 1)
            {

                while($row_col = mysqli_fetch_array($result_collection))
                {
                    $col_total_student = $row_col['total_student'];
                    $col_total_fee = $row_col['total_fee'];
                    $col_pta_fee = $row_col['pta_fee'];
                    $col_id_school = $row_col['id_school'];
                    $col_main_fee = $row_col['maintenance_fee'];
                    $col_electricity = $row_col['electricity'];

                    $result_sy = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM ptafee WHERE schoolyear = '$schoolyear'");

                    while($row_pta = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sy))
                    {
                        $pta_fee = $row_pta['pta_fee'];
                        $main_fee = $row_pta['maintenance_fee'];
                        $id_school = $row_pta['id_school'];
                        $electricity = $row_pta['electricity'];
                        $total = $row_pta['total'];

                        $total_pta_fee = ($count * $pta_fee) - $col_pta_fee;
                        $total_main_fee = ($count * $main_fee) - $col_main_fee;
                        $total_id_school = ($count * $id_school) - $col_id_school;
                        $total_electricity = ($count * $electricity) - $col_electricity;
                        $total_fee = ($count * $total) - $col_total_fee;

                        echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td><br></td>
                            <td><br></td>
                            <td><br></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style='font-size: 18px;'><b>Miscellaneous Fees</b></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>PTA Fee: </td>
                            <td style='padding-right: 480px;'>P" . $pta_fee . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Maintenance Fee: </td>
                            <td>P" . $main_fee . "</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>School ID: </td>
                            <td>P" . $id_school ." </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Electricity: </td>
                            <td><u>P" . $electricity . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</u></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Fees: </td>
                            <td>P" . $total . "</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><br></td>
                            <td><br></td>
                            <td><br></td>
                            <td><br></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style='font-size: 18px;'><b>School Year: </b></td>
                            <td>" . $schoolyear . "</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table border='0px' style='text-align: left;'>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Collected</b></td>
                            <td style='padding-right: 150px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><b>Collectibles</b></td>
                            <td style='padding-right: 150px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>PTA Fee: </td>
                            <td>P" . $col_pta_fee . "</td>
                            <td>PTA Fee: </td>
                            <td>P" . $total_pta_fee . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Maintenance Fee: </td>
                            <td>P" . $col_main_fee . "</td>
                            <td>Maintenance Fee: </td>
                            <td>P" . $total_main_fee . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>School ID:</td>
                            <td>P" . $col_id_school . "</td>
                            <td>School ID:</td>
                            <td>P" . $total_id_school . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Electricity:</td>
                            <td>P" . $col_electricity . "</td>
                            <td>Electricity:</td>
                            <td>P" . $total_electricity . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Total: </b></td>
                            <td>P" . $col_total_fee . "</td>
                            <td><b>Total: </b></td>
                            <td>P" . $total_fee . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><br></td>
                            <td><br></td>
                            <td><br></td>
                            <td><br></td>
                        </tr>
                        ";
                    }
                }
            }

            if($count_coll == 0)
            {
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'>
                        <b>THERE ARE NO DAILY TRANSACTION FOR THIS SCHOOL YEAR</b>
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                ";
            }

                echo "
            </table>

            <table border='0px;' style='text-align: left;'>
                <tr>
                    <td style='font-size: 18px;'><b>Previous Year: </b></td>
                    <td>" . $preschoolyear . "</td>
                    <td style='padding-right: 440px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                ";
            ?>

            <table border="0px;" style="text-align: left;">
            <?php               
            $student = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM student WHERE schoolyear = '$preschoolyear' AND status = 'Enrolled' OR status = 'Dropped'");
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($student);

            $result_collectionpre = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM collection WHERE schoolyear = '$preschoolyear' AND type_trans = 'Daily'");
            $count_collpre = mysqli_num_rows($result_collectionpre);

            if($count_collpre == 1)
            {

                while($row_col = mysqli_fetch_array($result_collectionpre))
                {
                    $col_total_student = $row_col['total_student'];
                    $col_total_fee = $row_col['total_fee'];
                    $col_pta_fee = $row_col['pta_fee'];
                    $col_id_school = $row_col['id_school'];
                    $col_main_fee = $row_col['maintenance_fee'];
                    $col_electricity = $row_col['electricity'];

                    $result_sy = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM ptafee WHERE schoolyear = '$preschoolyear'");

                    while($row_pta = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sy))
                    {
                        $pta_fee = $row_pta['pta_fee'];
                        $main_fee = $row_pta['maintenance_fee'];
                        $id_school = $row_pta['id_school'];
                        $electricity = $row_pta['electricity'];
                        $total = $row_pta['total'];

                        $total_pta_fee = ($count * $pta_fee) - $col_pta_fee;
                        $total_main_fee = ($count * $main_fee) - $col_main_fee;
                        $total_id_school = ($count * $id_school) - $col_id_school;
                        $total_electricity = ($count * $electricity) - $col_electricity;
                        $total_fee = ($count * $total) - $col_total_fee;

                        echo "

                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Collected</b></td>
                            <td style='padding-right: 150px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><b>Collectibles</b></td>
                            <td style='padding-right: 150px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>PTA Fee: </td>
                            <td>P" . $col_pta_fee . "</td>
                            <td>PTA Fee: </td>
                            <td>P" . $total_pta_fee . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Maintenance Fee: </td>
                            <td>P" . $col_main_fee . "</td>
                            <td>Maintenance Fee: </td>
                            <td>P" . $total_main_fee . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>School ID:</td>
                            <td>P" . $col_id_school . "</td>
                            <td>School ID:</td>
                            <td>P" . $total_id_school . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Electricity:</td>
                            <td>P" . $col_electricity . "</td>
                            <td>Electricity:</td>
                            <td>P" . $total_electricity . "</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Total: </b></td>
                            <td>P" . $col_total_fee . "</td>
                            <td><b>Total: </b></td>
                            <td>P" . $total_fee . "</td>
                        </tr>
                    ";
                    }
                }
            }

            if($count_collpre == 0)
            {
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th style='text-align: center;'>
                        <b>THERE ARE NO DAILY TRANSACTION FOR THIS SCHOOL YEAR</b>
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                ";
            }
            ?>

            </table>

                <?php
                $date = DATE("F j, Y");
                $time = DATE("g:i A");

                echo "
                    <table border='0px' style='text-align: left;'>
                        <tr>
                            <th><br></th>
                            <th><br></th>
                            <th><br></th>
                            <th><br></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th><br></th>
                            <th><br></th>
                            <th><br></th>
                            <th><br></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th style='font-size: 18px;'><b>Date: </b></th>
                            <th>" . $date . "</th>
                            <th style='font-size: 18px;'><b>Reprinted By: </b></th>
                            <th>" . $user . "</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <th style='font-size: 18px;'><b>Time: </b></th>
                            <th>" . $time . "</th>
                        </tr>
                        ";

            /*if($count_collpre == 0)
            {
                echo "
                <tr>
                    THERE ARE NO DAILY TRANSACTION FOR THE PREVIOUS SCHOOL YEAR
                </tr>
                ";
            }*/
            ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the last php for the report

```php
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('folio', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
//$dompdf->stream("report.pdf");
$dompdf->stream('report.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0));
?>
```

Comment: please provide some more information on your setup. Which technologies are available to you? what is the data source for the report? There are many many ways to generate pdfs, without some more details it will be hard to narrow down which one is right for you.

Comment: The details seem sufficient, but I was not entirely sure what you want to do. Are you have a problem generating the PDF, or is there something wrong with the generated PDF?